# Http 429 response while testing

Tags: java, http, testing, junit

Im testing my api and after 50 tests every next test is returning 429 instead of 200. Can you tell me how to fix it? How to inject rate limiter only to this test unit?

Comment: `429 Too Many Requests` is the HTTP status code you receive and its name is already giving it away. Seems like your API has some kind of [leaky-bucket filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) that only allows a certain amount of API calls within a given time. As you didn't include any hints on what framework your API is made of or how its configured, it's hard to give further advice.

Comment: I can not really post some screens unfortunatelly but ye i have set the limit for 50 requests, but i want it to stay as it is and only increase that number in tests scope.